# Edit web.config connection strings in production

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-config, connection-string

I'm quite new to ASP.NET development.
I'm trying to understand what is the "usual" way of configuring the connection string when deploying a SQL Server database into production. I learned that it is normal to have different connection strings between development and production, as mentioned [here](http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/a-quick-way-to-change-connection-between-local-and-production-databases.aspx) for instance.

I'm developing a small ASP.NET application that is going to run on an intranet; I'll have no access to the production server. 
Now, to my question: how can I let the "final" user configure the correct connection string? I know that my application will be installed by the IT people in the company, but how?

- Should they edit my web.config file?
- Should I provide a "configuration" page, where the user is going to write the connection string? (in this case: shuould I write the web.config file myself, programmatically?)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the experience you want the end-user to have. Easiest is just having them edit the web.config (either through notepad or through IIS)(You do know that IIS provides an editor for your web.config and specifically for connection strings, right?)

But the best user experience (imo) is if your installer can build the connection string through a series of questions. If they need to change it after the fact, they can edit manually or though IIS.

Comment: Well, my end-user should be experienced enough to edit the web.config; my concern was (1) if this is a good guideline, or if there are better way to do this and (2) web.config could contain more than the connection string, so this could be "dangerous"?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this is they already know the connection string using Web.config transformations. The idea is that they give the connection string, you set it up in your web.deploymentname.config, and when you publish / create package of your website, the value of the connection string will be changed auto-magically.

This answer describes how to do it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19356284/375304

Another solution if you do not know the connection string would be to use the Web Deploy Tool. This allows to provide an easy, step-by-step based UI with (among other) the possibility to set the connection string. It also makes packaging your website for deployment MUCH easier. Have a look at the video at the following link for more info:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

However, be aware that the Web Deploy Tool must be installed first on the IIS server (it is very easy to setup though) using the Web Platform Installer (which is very handy anyway, you should have it).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instance of how I would do it...

Editing my Web.Config file 
Note: the names: DefaultConnection, LocalConnection, livedbsource, localdbsource, localMachineName

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <!--Live-->
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=livedbsource;Initial Catalog=livedbname;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<!--Dev-->
<add name="LocalConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localdbsource;Initial Catalog=localdbname;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And for the ApplicationDbContext

```
    static string ServerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
    //setting what connection string to use - tenary operator
    static string ConnectionStringID = (ServerName == "localMachineName") ? "LocalConnection" : "DefaultConnection";
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(ConnectionStringID, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

On Windows 7 and higher, You can get the localMachineName pressing the Windows Logo and searching for System Information, then look for 'System Name'

Here is the YouTube video I did it in Visual Studio 2017 on a live project and it worked.

https://youtu.be/oKg6ewKhkYs