# Where to store global variables (like paths) in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to C# and am still in the process of figuring out the best practices for certain things.

I want to know where I could store settings such as paths (eg. For file uploads) and other assorted variables so that they can be accessed anywhere in the project.

Should I just create a class with static variables or is there a better approach to storing these settings?

Comment: In your Web.Config (or App.Config)? You can have different build settings and different config files for those. It also really depends on what you store.

Comment: For now I'm only interested in having a single place I can keep all paths I reference in my controllers. I'll look into those config files you mentioned.

Comment: If it's app-wide settings and paths then definitely the web.config  - also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284994/how-to-have-different-web-config-settings-for-my-local-machine . You can of course roll your own - but Web.Config has the benefit of restarting your server when you change it and upload a new version (well... kinda but I don't want to go into the uninteresting details)

Comment: There is not correct or wrong answer for this, it should be based on what is the best practices in your firm, what is available etc. For instance in my firm we have our own config store in a custom xml data store to save it which has its own security mechanism. There is wide range of possibilities here from app.config to external config stores. I suggest see what's expected out the business and decide one one.

Comment: Yes I can definitely see the value in using the web.config file. And thanks, I'll need to check tomorrow with the powers that be on what is required. Thanks for the feedback guys :)

Comment: probably the best options is a custom xml where place the keys of setting and a database table to store the value, this solution fit well in multi environments(DEV/STG/INT/PRD)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd better save this in the `web.config` since this can be changed after compilation.

The [`appSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx) element is reserved for this kind of functionality. You can even split this part off in a different file so it is totally clear this in your specific config.

Example `web.config` only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="DocumentDirectory" value="~/Documents" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Or:

`web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="appSettings.xml" />
</configuration>
```

And a separate `appSettings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
    <add key="DocumentDirectory" value="~/Documents" />
</appSettings>
```

You can [read those settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/610xe886(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;

Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);

if (config.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
{
    KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting = config.AppSettings.Settings["DocumentDirectory"];

    if (customSetting != null)
    {
        string directory = customSetting.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I access those values from my controllers though?

Comment: All right @Patrick-hofman , but in multiple enviroments how can this solution be applicable?

Comment: I prefer to split the settings to a different file. That makes deployment easier. In your deployment, create a `appSettings.xml.sample`. That contains a sample config file just like the one above. On deployment, you rename that file to `appSettings.xml` and do the config you want. Following this will also prevent that in a update deployment you will overwrite the `appSettings.xml` file.